# Отправка сообщений

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать отправку сообщений, а конкретно по варианту, как в соц сетях: прочитал пользователь или не прочитал его. Если есть какой-нибудь туториал на эту тему, то подкиньте, пожалуйста. Желательно, при помощи jQuery ajax чтобы было. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таблице БД, в которой сохраняются сообщение, добавляется поле для хранения статуса прочтения. Соответственно, если пользователь сообщение открыл - считаем его прочитанным и обновляем статус. В [vk.com](http://vk.com) сообщение считается прочитанным, если пользователь начал набирать ответ или провел над сообщением курсором.

Comment: а как можно сделать что только при нажатии на текст сообщения было это ?Ну само прочтение или хотя бы при нажатии на кнопку прочитал ?

Comment: Задача - изменить поле таблицы БД с 0 на 1 (или с 1 на 0 - тут уж на любителя). А событие, вызывающее это действие, можно выбрать любое.

Для клика по кнопке будет что-то вроде:

$("#button").click(function(){
 $.ajax(/*отправляем наш запрос на скрипт с командой изменения статуса*/);
});

Comment: А при открытии сообщения ?или наведении на его курсора как сделать ?

Comment: Открываем сообщение - обновляем статус.

А наведение курсора - тут подойдут события серии mouse*

Answer (score 2):

Для таблицы сообщений делаешь поле "прочитал". Когда пользователь подгружает себе сообщения - значит он их получил => помечаешь как прочитанное. jQuery ajax - это уже дизайн.